# Multisite /files/ URLs broken after server move

Tags: multisite, htaccess, apache

The file urls of all sub sites in my multisite install have stopped working after moving to a new server. The move was a straight site clone from WHM to WHM, so nothing has changed really. The new server uses Apache 2.4 instead of 2.2, and a new PHP/MySQL but that is the only change.

This is the type of url that no longer works...

```
subsite.maindomain.com/files/headway/cache/responsive-grid-d2119e4.css?ver=4.3.1
```

This works....

```
subsite.maindomain.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/16/files/headway/cache/responsive-grid-d2119e4.css?ver=4.3.1
```

My .htaccess looks like this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: check the DNS of your new cpanel. To subdomain multisite to work you must need to add an `A` record for the sub-domain `*.yourdomain.com`. I think you are missing that part.

Comment: Thanks but I already have that and the wildcard subdomains are working fine. Just these file alias links aren't working.